# Termux - Android(pip install --only-binay :all: mysqlclient --user)

Tags: python, android, mysql, django, termux

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.

Did you install mysqlclient?

$ pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient --user

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient
```

I am trying to execute a Python web-based Django project in Android.

How to solve this error? How can I be able to install required mysqlclient in termux?

Answer (score 0):

The package name is `mysql` not `mysqlclient`.

```bash
pip install mysql
```

And don't install a precompiled binary from PyPI. Most likely that won't work in termux.